# check mark character = "\u2713" - inconsistent print out

Tags: ruby, unicode, unicode-string

Inconsistent behavior.

```ruby
checkmark = "\u2713"
puts checkmark.encode('utf-8')   # this works - prints the 'checkmark' character

2713.upto(2713) {|i|
    puts '\u'.concat(i.to_s)    # this prints \u2713  (instead of expected 'checkmark')
}
```

In both cases - print the check box character.

Code: https://tio.run/##TY5NCsIwGET3OcWgi6SLBtSFbrxJQWKa0lBMSvIFFevZY@pPcTcwzHsT0vmes@6NHi4qDDhi1aTtfrNbsTFRxNJI47RvjeCJuvrAKwBrUG8jrj4METXGYF1ZUG/AlxkvBBWUJhMYm7kyjeTFnCo8JjuxAsJbxZvEpfZOKxJWkj/FWfKzfOmfc4CwLpJRLXwHcxtNEbT/2oo9Wc4v

Comment: single quotes vs double quotes. That's where the inconsistency is.

Comment: nope - I tried that already. You will get different error: "invalid Unicode escape". Example code: https://tio.run/##Tc5NCsIwEIbhfU7xURdJFw2oC914E0FimtJQTEoyQcV69pj6U9wNDPM@E9L5nrPujR4uKgw4oDqmzW69rdiYKGLZSOO0b43gibpmz2sAK1BvI64@DBENxmBduaDegC9nvBRUUJpMYGzuyjSSF/NU4zHZiZUQ3lSBK6m904qEleRPcUZ@yrf@eQ4Q1kUyqoXvYG6jKUD7z9bsyXJ@AQ

Comment: Indeed, I tried this myself now. In any case, single-quoted strings don't process most  backslash sequences, this included.

Comment: My Goal: I am trying to print few Unicode characters using a loop ... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

In ruby, you turn character codes into characters with `chr`

```
55.chr # => "7"
```

But this will fail for codes outside of ASCII range

```
10003.chr # RangeError (10003 out of char range)
# 10003 is 0x2713 in decimal
```

In this case, you need to specify the encoding.

```
10003.chr(Encoding::UTF_8) # => "✓"
```

Or use `Array#pack`

```
[10003].pack("U*") # => "✓"
```

Comment: I think it is also worth noting that `'\u' + '2713'` and `"\u2713"` are very different things due to when escape sequences are decoded. Also that `\u` works with hex rather than decimal.

Comment: @muistooshort: your comment should serve perfectly, I think. Thanks :)

Comment: Great: I need to check the hex vs. decimal. However, I get different result on Win7 platform:    C:\Users\ZZBGO>irb
irb(main):001:0> p RUBY_PLATFORM
"x64-mingw32"
=> "x64-mingw32"
irb(main):002:0> p RUBY_VERSION
"2.6.1"
=> "2.6.1"
irb(main):003:0> 10003.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
=> "\u2713"

Comment: @Adam: maybe it's the windows ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Works on my machine (and tio)

Comment: f = File.open('trash.txt', 'w'); 
100.upto(33500){|i|
 f << i.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
}

Answer (score 0):

This `u'\u2713'` works fine for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).